# Getting ReferenceError in Javascript/HTML Saying Function Not Defined

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

I am running some very vanilla HTML code with embedded javascript.  I am using "onClick" to reference a javascript function declared a few lines prior.  The script is simple and is only supposed to display an alert with "About" info in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyApp - Main Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyApp.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="CONTAINER">
             <div id="ONEIT1">
                 <img src="oneit_black.jpg">
             </div>
             <div id="ONEIT2">
                 <img src="oneit_black.jpg">
             </div>
             <div id="BANNER">
                 <h1>MyApplication</h1>
                 <h3>Main Menu</h3>
             </div>
             <div id="MENUBAR">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function ABOUT_ALERT(node)
                    {{
                        return alert("Version 1.00");
                    }}
                 </script>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="mailto:somebody@email.com">Contact Admin</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" onclick="return ABOUT_ALERT(this);">About MyApp</a></li>
                     <li>Something</li>
                     <li><form action="MyApp.py" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="VAR_STATE" value="LOGOUT">
                        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
                     </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the alert fails to open or show up, and when I open it in F12 developer tools, I see that it is telling me my function ABOUT_ALERT is not defined:

ReferenceError: ABOUT_ALERT is not defined

I have used this exact same code elsewhere in other web-based apps with no issue.  Does anybody see what I am doing wrong here?  NOTE: The double "{{" and "}}" around my javascript function is due to the fact this is being run from Python and I typically do a lot of {xyz} formatting/replacements so had to use doubles.

Answer (score 0):

```
                function ABOUT_ALERT(node)
                {{
                    return alert("Version 1.00");
                }}
```

Should be:

```
                function ABOUT_ALERT(){
                    alert("Version 1.00");
                }
```

Also, your function is declared to accept an argument and you are passing one to the function, but the function isn't doing anything with the argument.

Also, you don't need any of your `return` keywords since no value is being sent anywhere.

Lastly, put your JavaScript in the `head` section of the web page or just before the close of the `body` for better readability.

```js
                    function ABOUT_ALERT() {
                        alert("Version 1.00");
                    }
```

```html
        <div id="CONTAINER">
             <div id="ONEIT1">
                 <img src="oneit_black.jpg">
             </div>
             <div id="ONEIT2">
                 <img src="oneit_black.jpg">
             </div>
             <div id="BANNER">
                 <h1>MyApplication</h1>
                 <h3>Main Menu</h3>
             </div>
             <div id="MENUBAR">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="mailto:somebody@email.com">Contact Admin</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" onclick="ABOUT_ALERT();">About MyApp</a></li>
                     <li>Something</li>
                     <li><form action="MyApp.py" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="VAR_STATE" value="LOGOUT">
                        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
                     </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a great answer, but your code worked for me when I ran it in Chrome